# Saving a string with a boolean variable connected

Tags: android

I have a ListView that displays tasks that the user adds, I currently have it saving a string for the name to an array which the listview then loads from. But I need to save the string entered by the user and whether the task they have added is completed. I considered using shared preferences. Here is what I have done already:

[Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX842.png)

```js
package com.swapsy.jack.bucketlist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.renderscript.ScriptGroup;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;
    Button mShowComplete;
    FloatingActionButton mAddTask;
    boolean showComplete;
    ListView mlvToDoList;
    Context mContext;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //--------- Advertisement ------------
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("5DF76A39EE68E7EAD108ACDD62B2728C") //Change to "ca-app-pub-1914598267234410/4838548938"
                .build();

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBanner);

        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        //---------------Main code---------------

        mShowComplete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowCompleted);
        mAddTask = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddFab);
        mlvToDoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvToDoList);

        String[] bucket = new String[] {

        };

        final List<String> bucket_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(bucket));

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, bucket_list);

        mlvToDoList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        mAddTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_input, null);
                final EditText mTaskNameInput = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.inputText);
                Button mAdd = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

                mAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Add task

                        bucket_list.add(mTaskNameInput.toString());

                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        mBuilder.setView(null);

                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
        mShowComplete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (showComplete) {
                    //true
                    mShowComplete.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_enabled, 0, 0, 0);
                    showComplete = false;
                } else {
                    //false
                    mShowComplete.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_disabled, 0, 0, 0);
                    showComplete = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void saveList() {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to with  a getter and setter

```
class Structure{
private String string;
private boolean bln;

// constructor
public Structure(String name, boolean bln) {
    this.string = name;
    this.bln= bln;
}

// getter
public String getString() { return string; }
public boolean getBln() { return bln; }
// setter

public void setString(String string) { this.string = string; }
public void setBln(boolean bln) { this.bln= bln; }

}
```

Usage:

```
 Structure struc = new Structure("", false);
        struc.setBln(your_boolean);
        boolean bln = struc.getBln();
        struc.setString(your_string);
        String s= struc.getString();
```

To use this as array

```
Structure[] array = new Structure[10];
array[0] = new Structure();
array[0].setID("yourid");

String id = array[0].getID();

// with arraylist
ArrayList<Structure> arraylist = new ArrayList<Structure>();
arraylist.add(new YourCustomObject());
arraylist.get(0).setID("yourid");

String id = arraylist.get(0).getID();
```

Comment: Would this work for saving and retrieving multiple strings and booleans?

Comment: It will if you make the string and Boolean into arrays.

Comment: At the moment I have it loading from an array in my main activity, do you mean storing it in an array within the class? Also thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a code snippet to clarify how I save and load, using an array, to a listview?

Comment: Check the answer I have edited it with the code snippet

Comment: Is that in the main activity or in the class?

Comment: In the activity

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by custom object, and .setID and .getID return errors.

Comment: You can ignore the setID and getId. Its just to set an id for individual array elements.

Comment: So do I leave them out?

Comment: Yeah. If you find no need for it then you can

Comment: Where does the id come from though, do I need to write a function to increment an id?

Comment: To generate one for each element you might have to write a one.

Comment: It seems like it is loading from the class into an array which stores multiple tasks, but the class can only store one task at a time, but I need to be able to save the data to load when the app is closed and re-opened.

Comment: Oh. Then you should use a data base